# Big Theta example

Tags: big-o

I'm having trouble with this question. I know that for one function to equal big theta of another, the limit as n tends towards infinity of f(n)/g(n) has to equal a non-zero constant. But I've never evaluated a limit with summations (let alone two summations with one over the other). Could someone explain or point me in the right direction? Thanks!

[image: PROBLEM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are *geometric series*. There is a standard formula for evaluating them:

[image]

So the question becomes:

[image]

Which is **false** as `3^n` grows exponentially faster than `2^n`, so they cannot be of the same complexity class.